# How to use custom comparator in Rust?

Tags: rust, comparator

I am trying to sort vector with help of custom comparator. What is the proper way to do it in Rust?

My code

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![0, -4, 1, 2, 3];
    v.sort_by(|a, b| { 
        if a.abs() < b.abs() {
            return Ordering::Less;
        }
        return  Ordering::Greater;
    });
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

I have an error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `abs` found for reference `&{integer}` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:6:14
  |
6 |         if a.abs() < b.abs() {
  |              ^^^ method not found in `&{integer}`
```

Comment: As a side note, most custom orderings can be achieved more easily using `sort_by_key()`. You should only use `sort_by()` if `sort_by_key()` doesn't work for your use case.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler just needs little help to figure the type out: add a type annotation

- On the `Vec` declaration: `let mut v: Vec<i32> = vec![...]`
- Or on the `Vec`'s items: `vec![0i32, -4, 1, 2, 3]`
- Or on the closure: `|a: &i32, b| { ... }`.

Answer (score 5):

Chayim is correct, but just to add on, the ordering you've defined isn't an ordering at the moment. It never has a case for equal elements (comparing `3` and `3` will result in a `Ordering::Greater` result).

You could add one explicitly, but you can also use [`Ord::cmp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#tymethod.cmp) to do the three-way comparison for you.

```
let mut v: Vec<i32> = vec![0, -4, 1, 2, 3];
v.sort_by(|a, b| {
  a.abs().cmp(&b.abs())
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be written most concisely with [`sort_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by_key).

```rs
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<i32> = vec![0, -4, 1, 2, 3];
    v.sort_by_key(|a| a.abs());
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```